# Quote a filename in a script passed to chmod?

Tags: macos, command-line, bash, unix

I'm having trouble quoting a filename that's eventually passed to `chmod`. The script was originally written for SSH's `StrictModes` and `authorized_keys`, but I had to expand it due to a bad `UMASK` that caused some filesystem discomfort. The script is below, and its producing boatloads of:

```
chmod: /Users/<user>/Library/Application: No such file or directory
chmod: Support/TextMate/Managed/Bundles/HTML.tmbundle/Macros/Delete: No such file or directory
chmod: whitespace: No such file or directory
chmod: between: No such file or directory
chmod: tags.plist: No such file or directory
...
chmod: /Users/<user>/Library/Caches/com.operasoftware.Opera/Media: No such file or directory
chmod: Cache/index: No such file or directory
cut: stdin: Illegal byte sequence
...
```

I've tried a few workarounds, but none of them have helped. I tried double quoting like `""$file""`, but the issue persisted. I also tried the back ticks (that are discouraged in this case), but the issue persisted.

The closest I got to actually quoting was the dysfunctional `"\"""$file""\""`. But then `chmod` complained the filename (with quotes) was not a real file:

```
$ sudo ~/fix-perms.sh
chmod: "/Users/Shared/.localized": No such file or directory
chmod: "/Users/<user>/.CFUserTextEncoding": No such file or directory
chmod: "/Users/<user>/.lesshst": No such file or directory
```

How do I quote the filename that comes out of `find` that gets passed onto `chmod`? Or how do I get `chmod` to take the filename as a single argument?

---

```
$ cat ~/fix-perms.sh 
#!/bin/bash

# Directories
find /Users/* -type d -exec chmod 0700 {} \;
find /Users/Shared -type d -exec chmod 0777 {} \;

# Files
for file in `find /Users/* -type f`;
do
    if [ `file "$file" | cut -d":" -f 2 | grep -i -c executable` -eq 0 ];
    then
        `chmod 0600 "$file"`
    else
        `chmod 0700 "$file"`
    fi
done

for user in `ls -A /Users`;
do
    if [ -e "/Users/$user/.ssh/authorized_keys" ];
    then
        chmod 0600 "/Users/${user}/.ssh/authorized_keys"
    fi
done
```

Comment: Are you invested in bash scripting or are there other options you would accept? If you're bash, I might be able to rework things to be `find | xargs sudo chmod` instead of unrolling everything in a for loop where spaces are causing you grief to iterate over the variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue by changing `IFS` to `IFS=$(echo -en "\n\b")` and *not* quoting the filename. `IFS` is ***[Internal Field Separator](http://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/$IFS)***, it is used (among others) for word splitting after shell expansions, and it includes a space by default.

I found the `IFS` trick at nixCraft's [BASH Shell: For Loop File Names With Spaces](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/handling-filenames-with-spaces-in-bash.html).

```
$ cat fix-perms.sh
#!/bin/bash

SAVED_IFS=$IFS
IFS=$(echo -en "\n\b")

# Directories
chmod 0755 /Users
find /Users/* -type d -exec chmod 0700 {} \;
find /Users/Shared -type d -exec chmod 0777 {} \;

# Files
for file in `find /Users/* -type f`;
do
    if [ `file "$file" | cut -d":" -f 2 | grep -i -c executable` -eq 0 ];
    then
        chmod 0600 "$file"
    else
        chmod 0700 "$file"
    fi
done

for user in `ls -A /Users`;
do
    if [ -e "/Users/$user/.ssh/authorized_keys" ];
    then
        chmod 0600 "/Users/${user}/.ssh/authorized_keys"
    fi
done

IFS=$SAVED_IFS
```

Comment: I can't really recommend this method, since it'll fail for filenames with linefeeds (or bells? why's that there...). Suppose a user created a file named `a\n*\nb` -- it'll be parsed into three words: "/Users/something/a", \*, and "b"; then the \* will get expanded into a list of files *and subdirectories* in the directory you're in, and the script will then change their permissions (maybe wrong, since the subdirectories aren't executable). But your users probably won't do this. Probably...

Comment: @Gordon - I did not look up the shell meta characters, but I meant to. Thanks for telling me about the bell... Why in the world is `\b` there, but not `\t`? Naively, I thought `\b` was either the tab or backspace. I kinda understood the backspace, but the bell makes no sense to me.

Comment: @Gordon - apparently, the Bash page uses an incorrect assumption for OS X. On OS X under HFS+, filenames can contain `\0`; see [Mac OS X Lion: What are invalid characters for a file name?](http://superuser.com/q/326103) on Super User. A leading `\0` is probably a good way for a virus to hide itself...

Answer (score 3):

fwiw, `find [options] -print0`, when used in conjunction with (piped to) `xargs -0 [options]`, handles filenames with spaces, without messing with `for` loops or `IFS`:

```
find /Users ! -path '/Users/Shared*' -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -I {} \
    bash -c 'if [[ "$(file -b --mime-type -- "{}")" = "application/x-mach-binary" ]]; then
                 chmod 700 "{}"
             else
                 chmod 600 "{}"
             fi'
```

Comment: thanks @patrix, that's better than what I would have come up with.

Comment: Yeah, there's so many ways to do things with the shell.... (I find it frustrating at times).

Comment: Slight alternative: `find /path -type d -maxdepth 1 ! -perm 0700 -exec chmod 0755 {} \; ` The `-maxdepth #` is arbitrary, sometimes you don't need or want to go too far down tree.

Answer (score 0):

`find` can handle spaces in file names. Your `for loops` are causing the problems. You can put your logic in multiple `find` commands. Not every directory in a user's home folder should be accessible to only them self. Public and Sites come to mind. You can fix them separately in another find command.

```
find /Users/* ! -path '/Users/Shared*'  -type d ! \( -name Public -o -name Sites \) -exec chmod 0700 {} +
```

The command excludes the Shared directory along with Public and Sites directories then changes the permissions on the remaining directories.

You can use `+` in your `find` statements to have `find` act as if it were `xargs`.

```
find /Users/Shared -type d -exec chmod 0777 {} +
```

Assuming that the executable files in a user's home folder are application bundles then you could do this.

```
find /Users/* ! -path '/Users/Shared*' type f ! perm -755 -exec chmod 0600 {} +
```

Comment: Thanks fd0. *"find can handle spaces in file names. Your for loops are causing the problems."* - OK, good, I'll take your word for it. Now what? You don't tell really me how to fix it. (Don't worry about `Shared` or `$HOME/Public`. That's icing on the cake. The primary concern is permissions on home directories).

Answer (score 0):

mtklr's (and Patrix') solution will work, but I find it's simpler to use a `while read` loop when dealing with a file list from `find ... -print0`:

```
find /Users '!' -path '/Users/Shared*' -type f -print0 |
    while IFS= read -d '' -r file; do
        if file "$file" | grep -iq ": .*executable"; then
            chmod 700 "$file"
        else
            chmod 600 "$file"
        fi
    done
```

`read -d ''` uses nulls as a delimiter. I also used  `-r` to prevent it from trying to parse escapes, and `IFS=` to prevent it trimming whitespace at the end of the filename (and since it's a prefix to the `read` command, it only applies to that one and you don't have to set it back afterward).

BTW, I also used `if ... | grep -q ...` -- the `-q` tells `grep` not to output anything, but its exit status will only succeed if it found at least one match. And since `if` just tests the exit status of the command in it, that's all that's needed.

BTW, this is mostly based on [BashFAQ #20: How can I find and safely handle file names containing newlines, spaces or both?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/020). I recommend giving it a look...